# Cant set pageSize limit in yii2 rest or activeDataProvider

Tags: rest, yii, pagination, yii2, yii-rest

I cant set value of ActiveDataProvider (pagination) pageSize in rest app
in order to change items in per page.
This is my sample code in controller

```
class EndpointController extends ActiveController
{
public $modelClass = 'common\models\Endpoint';
//     public $serializer = [
//         'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
//         'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    // //         'metaEnvelope' => false
//     ];
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    \Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = null;
}
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        'tokenParam' => 'access_token',
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
protected function verbs()
{
    $verbs = parent::verbs();
    unset($verbs['update'], $verbs['create'], $verbs['delete'],         $verbs['view'], $verbs['index'][1]);
//         $verbs['index'][] = 'POST';
    return $verbs;
}

public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['update'], $actions['create'], $actions['delete'], $actions['view'], $actions['options']);
    return $actions;
}
public function prepareDataProvider()
{
//         $activData = new ActiveDataProvider([
//             'query' => Endpoint::find(),
//             'pagination' => [
//                 'pageSize' => 2,
//             ]
//         ]);
//         return $activData;
}

public function actionIndex()
{
//         $activData = new ActiveDataProvider([
//             'query' => Endpoint::find(),
//             'pagination' => [
//                 'pageSize' => 2,
//             ]
//         ]);
    //         return $activData;
}    
}
```

My model has basic template and I tested all solution on internet before but i had no effect

Comment: what do you mean  ?  your relevant code  is commented ...

Comment: @scaisEdge I commented this code to say I tested this solution before.

Comment: Seems that you have already found the solution .. well ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by answer [JamesLeon](https://github.com/JamesLeon)
commennted on [github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/13544#issuecomment-278391403)